# How to make table lines match

Tags: tables, line

I'm having trouble with my table and don't have any idea how to fix it. I just don't know why the lines do not meet... It looks like this:

[image]

I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.6\textwidth}
      \begin{tabular}{|l |l ||c |c|}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{|l||}{} & a & b\\
      \midrule
      \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{c} &  d & e \\  
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{f} 
 & g &  \\  
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{h} 
 & i & j \\  
\hline
 & k & l & m \\  
\cline{2-4} 
n & o & p & q\\
\cline{2-4} 
 & r & s & t \\   
\hline 
 & u & v & w \\   
\cline{2-4} 
x & y & z & aa \\   
\cline{2-4} 
 & ab & ac & ad \\   
\hline  
 & ae & af & ag \\   
\cline{2-4} 
ah & ai & aj & ak \\   
\cline{2-4}  
 & al & am & an \\    
      \bottomrule 
      \end{tabular}
      \end{adjustbox}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

I'm sure it can't be that hard, although for me, it is. So thanks for any helping comments! :)

Comment: `booktabs` is designed for *not* using vertical rules, and doesn't work well with them. If you really need the vertical rules, the simples fix is to use `\hline` instead of the rules from `booktabs` (`\toprule`,`\midrule`,`\bottomrule`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use vertical rules in a tabular environment, don't use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package. If you do have to use vertical rules and hence can't use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc but still want the well-spaced appearance of horizontal rules that the booktabs macros provide, I suggest you resort to (typographic) struts. That way, the vertical lines will still be continuous.

The following example implements this idea, using code I gleaned from an article written by Claudio Beccari that was published in *TeX & TUG News* in 1993. (Yes, I really have been using TeX and LaTeX that long...) Use `\Tstrut` to create extra space to the line above, `\Bstrut` for extra space to the line below, and `\TBstrut` ("top and bottom strut") for more spacing to both the lines above and below the macro's insertion. In the code, notice the `\TBstrut` in the first line, the `\Tstrut` in the second line, and the `\Bstrut` in the bottom line of the tabular.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
%% code from article by Claudio Beccari in TeX&TUG News, 1993
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}      % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}}% "bottom" strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut}    % "top and bottom" strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l |l ||c |c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{}  &  a & b\TBstrut\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{c} &  d & e\Tstrut \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{f}
 & g &  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{h}
 & i & j \\
\hline
 & k & l & m \\
\cline{2-4}
n & o & p & q\\
\cline{2-4}
 & r & s & t \\
\hline
 & u & v & w \\
\cline{2-4}
x & y & z & aa \\
\cline{2-4}
 & ab & ac & ad \\
\hline
 & ae & af & ag \\
\cline{2-4}
ah & ai & aj & ak \\
\cline{2-4}
 & al & am & an\Bstrut \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that you like to have more vertical space above/below cells content and also like to have vertical rules. This combination, is clearly explained in Mico's answer, is not possible by use of ˙booktabs` rules. Beside solution proposed by Mico also exist packages, which can add more vertical space without use of struts:

- `mdwtab`, an old not maintained package, not compatible with `colortbl` package (rows, columns, cells can't be colored), which has own syntax for determined additional space above/below cells' contents
- `tabu`, unfortunately also not maintained package, which provide macro `\tabulinesep` for additional vertical space above and/or below cells content (many people not recommend to use it because it is quite buggy, but my experiences with it is bad)
- `makecell`, which provide macros `\setcellgapes{<gap size>}` and `\makegapedcells`. Later macro is not compatible with  `colortbl` package.

Beside mentioned also exist other packages with which I'm less familiar. Example of their use:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l | l || c | c |}
    \hlx{hv}
\mcc{\texttt{mdwtab}}
                &   a   &   b       \\  \hlx{vhv}
\mcc{c}         &   d   &   e       \\  \hlx{vhv}
\mcc{f}         &   g   &           \\  \hlx{vhv}
\mcc{h}         &   i   &   j       \\  \hlx{vhv}
        &   k   &   l   &   m       \\  \hlx{vc{2-4}v}
n       &   o   &   p   &   q       \\  \hlx{vc{2-4}v}
        &   r   &   s   &   t       \\  \hlx{vhv}
%
        &   u   &   v   &   w       \\  \hlx{vc{2-4}v}
x       &   y   &   z   &   aa      \\  \hlx{vc{2-4}v}
        &   ab  &   ac  &   ad      \\  \hlx{vhv}
%
        &   ae  &   af  &   ag      \\  \hlx{vc{2-4}v}
ah      &   ai  &   aj  &   ak      \\  \hlx{vc{2-4}v}
        &   al  &   am  &   an      \\  \hlx{vh}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\tabulinesep =_5pt^5pt
\begin{tabu} {|l | l || c | c |}
    \hline
\mcc{}%\texttt{tabu}}
                &   a   &   b       \\  \hline
\mcc{c}         &   d   &   e       \\  \hline
\mcc{f}         &   g   &           \\  \hline
\mcc{h}         &   i   &   j       \\  \hline
        &   k   &   l   &   m       \\  \cline{2-4}
n       &   o   &   p   &   q       \\  \cline{2-4}
        &   r   &   s   &   t       \\  \hline
%
        &   u   &   v   &   w       \\  \cline{2-4}
x       &   y   &   z   &   aa      \\  \cline{2-4}
        &   ab  &   ac  &   ad      \\  \hline
%
        &   ae  &   af  &   ag      \\  \cline{2-4}
ah      &   ai  &   aj  &   ak      \\  \cline{2-4}
        &   al  &   am  &   an      \\  \hline
\end{tabu}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|l||}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l | l || c | c |}
    \hline
\mcc{\texttt{makecell}}
                &   a   &   b       \\  \hline
\mcc{c}         &   d   &   e       \\  \hline
\mcc{f}         &   g   &           \\  \hline
\mcc{h}         &   i   &   j       \\  \hline
        &   k   &   l   &   m       \\  \cline{2-4}
n       &   o   &   p   &   q       \\  \cline{2-4}
        &   r   &   s   &   t       \\  \hline
%
        &   u   &   v   &   w       \\  \cline{2-4}
x       &   y   &   z   &   aa      \\  \cline{2-4}
        &   ab  &   ac  &   ad      \\  \hline
%
        &   ae  &   af  &   ag      \\  \cline{2-4}
ah      &   ai  &   aj  &   ak      \\  \cline{2-4}
        &   al  &   am  &   an      \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to draw vertical rules compatible with the rules of `\booktabs` (although this is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`), you should use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|c||c|c|}
\toprule
\Block{1-2}{}     &    & a  & b  \\ \Hline\Hline
\Block[l]{1-2}{c} &    & d  & d  \\ \Hline
\Block[l]{1-2}{f} &    & g  & d  \\ \Hline
\Block[l]{1-2}{h} &    & i  & j  \\ \Hline
\Block{3-1}{n}    & k  & l  & m  \\ \Hline
                  & o  & p  & q  \\ \Hline
                  & r  & s  & t  \\ \Hline
\Block{3-1}{x}    & u  & v  & w  \\ \Hline
                  & y  & z  & aa \\ \Hline
                  & ab & ac & ad \\ \Hline
\Block{3-1}{ah}   & ae & af & ag \\ \Hline
                  & ai & aj & ak \\ \Hline
                  & al & am & an \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]